# ¿Cómo mostrar datos en vista para tabla relacionada de tipo Inherits (Discriminator) con EF MVC?

Tags: c#, base-de-datos, entity-framework, herencia, model-view-controller

Estoy actualmente para obtener los datos de una tabla **Persona** desde una tabla finca que tiene una relación con llave foránea a dicha tabla persona. El problema es al parecer por la **herencia** de dicha tabla persona a otra tabla **Asociado** "Eso creo". Desde la vista puedo visualizar los datos de la **Finca** en una tabla pero no los de la persona relacionada usando:

```html
@model IEnumerable<catanei.Models.Finca>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2> Gestión de Fincas</h2>

<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.Label("Nombre De Finca")
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.Label("Propietario")
        </th>
        <th>@Html.Label("Acción a Realizar")</th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td class="danger">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.nombre)
        </td >
        <td class="danger">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Persona.FullName)
        </td>
   <tr>    
}

</table>
```

Si tengo la siguiente relación (Disculpar el paint):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y planteo los modelos de dichas tablas de esta forma:

```
public class Persona
{
    [Key]
    [StringLength(7)]
    public string codigo { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(20)]
    [Index("IX_cedula", 1, IsUnique = true)]
    [Display(Name = "Cédula")]
    public string cedula { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(30)]
    [Display(Name = "Nombre")]
    public string nombre { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20)]
    [Display(Name = "Telefono")]
    public string telefono { get; set; }

}

 public class Asociado:Persona
{      
    //Lista de fincas
    [Required]
    public ICollection<Finca> fincas { get; set; }

}

 public class Finca
{
    [Key]
    [StringLength(7)]
    public string codigo { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(30)]
    [Index("IX_nombreFinca", 1, IsUnique = true)]
    [Display(Name = "Nombre")]
    public string nombre { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Persona")]
    public string fkPropietario { get; set; }

    public virtual Persona Persona { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Disculpen los errores gramaticales en la pregunta, no sabia que no podía editar la pregunta una vez publicada.

Comment: En el HTML aparece un campo de la tabla para mostrar un titulo de vereda o acciones a realizar, IGNOREN estos campos. La pregunta recae en como obtener el dato del propietario o PERSONA relacionada al modelo de la FINCA

Comment: Ahora bien en no se piense que el error es por denotar el item como item.Persona.FullName ; FullName corresponde a un dato del modelo Persona que no puse en la descripción el cual concatena el nombre de la persona con su apellido (En el problema las clases modelos están reducidas). Si denoto item.Persona.nombre tampoco me muestra el valor